# How to Import findbug/PMD in Sonar Qube

Tags: java, sonarqube, findbugs, sonar-runner, pmd

How can I import configuration files for FindBug/PMD (XML format) in sonar Qube? I know the way but where to find those XML files to import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the explanation of SonarQube and its integration

> The SonarQube Java plugin alone already covers all the Checkstyle and PMD rules - which is why the related plugins are no more bundled in SonarQube. So you can get rid of those plugins and forget the related rules.
>
> Concerning Findbugs, most rules are complementary to the SonarQube Java plugin rules. There's no "Sonar way with Findbugs" profile anymore because that's the convention for all the language plugin to have only a "Sonar way" profile.

For more information, you can refer to the original post at
[SonarQube - Combining Sonar way, FindBugs, PMD and Checkstyle without duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28108369/sonarqube-combining-sonar-way-findbugs-pmd-and-checkstyle-without-duplicates/28111076#28111076)

Comment: thanks for the link, but i am using sonar qube 4.3 and it has default "sonar way with findbugs" but no PMD. It would be great if i could update this rule with latest findbugs rule. Thanks. @Qiu, Yes you are correct.

Comment: Bare in mind that response dates back to 2015. The development rate of both Checkstyle and PMD have ramped up a lot since then, and have included rules which are not covered by SonarQube AFAIK.